# jQuery dependent fields (reset value), add to MySQL same name attribute fields

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

I have setup a 4phases multiple dependent dropdown fields. I want to select region then country, owned or franchise and finally store name.

My issues:
1)  Show/hide works OK but doesn’t reset values when I choose “-”. This mean that I can choose one store, then change my opinion, choose another option from upper field category and choose a second store. The POST will have both values. I want to reset the first value when I choose another option

2)  Store names have all name attribute store_name. I can’t managed to make it record correctly on mysql db while I used implode().

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#region").bind("change",function(){
        var selectedValue=$(this).val().toLowerCase();
        switch(selectedValue){
            case "asia": 
                $("#country_asia").show();  
                $("#country_america").hide()
                $("#country_europe").hide()
                break;
            case "america": 
                $("#country_asia").hide();  
                $("#country_america").show();
                $("#country_europe").hide();    
                break;
            case "europe":  
                $("#country_asia").hide();  
                $("#country_america").hide();
                $("#country_europe").show();    
                break;
            case "-":   
                $("#country_asia").hide()   
                $("#country_america").hide()
                $("#country_europe").hide()
                break;
                        }
    });
    $("#country_europe_dd").change(function()
{
  var selectedValue=$(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if(selectedValue == "greece")
  {
    $("#owned_gr").show();
  }
  else if(selectedValue == "-")
  {
    $("#owned_gr").hide();
  }
})
    $("#owned_gr_dd").change(function()
{
  var selectedValue=$(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if(selectedValue == "own")
  {
    $("#store_name").show();
    $("#store_name_greece_fran").hide();
  }
  else if(selectedValue == "fran")
  {
    $("#store_name_greece_fran").show();
    $("#store_name").hide();
  }
  else if(selectedValue == "-")
  {
    $("#store_name").hide();
    $("#store_name_greece_fran").hide();
  }
})
});
    </script>
```

Form:

```
<div class="form-group region required" data-cid="region">
  <label class="control-label" for="region">Region</label>

<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></i></span>
  <select class="select form-control" onChange="displayForm(this)" id="region" name="region">
    <option  value="-">- Select -</option>
    <option  value="america">America</option>
    <option  value="asia">Asia</option>
    <option  value="europe">Europe</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>

<div id="country_europe" class="form-group country_europe required" style="display: none" data-cid="country_europe">
  <label class="control-label" for="country">Country</label>

<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></i></span>
  <select class="select form-control" id="country_europe_dd" name="country">
    <option  value="-">- Select -</option>
    <option  value="cyprus">Cyprus</option>
    <option  value="france">France</option>
    <option  value="germany">Germany</option>
    <option  value="greece">Greece</option>
    <option  value="iceland">Iceland</option>
    <option  value="italy">Italy</option>
    <option  value="netherlands">Netherlands</option>
    <option  value="norway">Norway</option>
    <option  value="serbia">Serbia</option>
    <option  value="switzerland">Switzerland</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>

<div id="owned_gr" class="form-group owned_gr required" style="display: none" data-cid="owned_gr">
  <label class="control-label" for="owned_gr">Owned or Franchise ?</label>

<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></i></span>
  <select class="select form-control" id="owned_gr_dd" name="owned">
    <option  value="-">- Select -</option>
    <option  value="own">Owned</option>
    <option  value="fran">Franchise</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>

<div id="store_name" class="form-group store_name required" style="display: none" data-cid="store_name">
  <label class="control-label" for="store_name">Store Name - Greece (Owned)</label>

<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-buysellads"></i> </span>
<select class="form-control" name="store_name[]" id="store_name_gr_owned"
    data-rule-required="true" >
  <option  value="-">- Select -</option>
  <option  value="option1">Option1</option>
  <option  value="option2">Option2</option>
  </select>
</div>

</div>

<div id="store_name_greece_fran" class="form-group store_name_greece_fran required" style="display: none" data-cid="store_name_greece_fran">
  <label class="control-label" for="store_name_greece_fran">Store Name - Greece (Franchise)</label>

<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-buysellads"></i> </span>
<select class="form-control" name="store_name[]" id="store_name_greece_fran"   
    data-rule-required="true" >
  <option  value="">- Select -</option>
  <option  value="athens">Athens</option>
  <option  value="crete">Crete</option>
  </select>
</div>

</div>
```

PHP:

```
$store_name = implode($_POST['store_name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: From your comment below, sounds like solving #1 will also solve #2.

For #1, Whenever you `hide` an element, set its value to `-` as well. E.g.

```
case "asia": 
    $("#country_asia").show();  
    $("#country_america").hide();
    $("#country_america").val("-");
    $("#country_europe").hide();
    $("#country_europe").val("-");      
    break;
```

Or, using vanilla JS:

```
document.getElementById("country_europe_dd").value = '-';
```

<strike>For #2, I can't see anything wrong with your code. Can you elaborate? Maybe include sample output of what you're seeing for `$store_name`?</strike>

Comment: Thank you Luke. I tried .val but didn't work. To give you an example about #2 (which is connected with #1): I select region europe, then greece, then owned i choose store_name, i select franchise i choose another store_name and when i submit the form the recorded value is both store names together.

Comment: Hm, I copied your code locally and `val` worked fine. What version of JQuery (if any) are you using? Do you know why `val` didn't work?

Comment: You can use vanilla JS: `document.getElementById("country_europe_dd").value = '-';`

It sounds like if you just reset the other `store_name` dropdowns then problem #2 will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I have to go one step further on jQuery and use val(). I reset other category values when i select specific values on the field i choose

```
    $("#store_name_greece_fran_dd").change(function()
{
    var selectedValue=$(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if(selectedValue == "athens" || selectedValue == "athens" || selectedValue == "crete" || selectedValue == "crete")
  {
    $("#store_name_owned_dd").val('');
  }
})
```